# Is there an in-universe evidence reflecting that Clark Kent is Methodist (as opposed to other denominations)?

Tags: dc, comics, superman

As per Elliot S! Maggin's notes,  Clark Kent is Methodist.

Is there clear **in-universe** canon reflection of that?

ANY canon is OK, comics, TV, animation.

I'm fine with any kind of support, either in the dialog, or some art (e.g. Clark coming out of a church that he is implied to belong to and that is unambiguously Methodist?).

Comment: Highly relevant: [Is there any **official** confirmation that Superman was meant to “be Jewish”?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15742/2865)

Comment: I would think, seeing how S. Maggin is a famed writer of Superman, we would be able to accept his word for it. He would be a canon source.

Comment: Well, since [Superman comes from India](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNt63Pj2qV4), I doubt he is either.

Comment: @Thaddeus - sorry, bad wording. I meant "Does this fact get actually reflected in the in-universe canon?". I edited. If you were the one downvoting, please see if the edit assuages your concern that the question is inane.

Comment: First of all, I rarely (read that as almost never) down-vote. If I am unhappy with a question, or think the question should not exist at all, I just vote to close. Second, the question is a fair one given the religious nature of our society overall. I am not religious, but I understand how such an icon (with religious overtones no less) might elicit such an interest in this personal character trait.

Comment: @Thaddeus - actually, my interest is a lot more academic. There are writer's notes in a universe. I want to know if they were ever translated into the works themselves. I don't particularly care about character implications to CK/SM in this case.

Comment: Given the history of the characters, I am not sure if there were any true "writer's notebooks" in place. They were so busy back in the day pushing the characters into print, stories would contradict each other within a couple of issues. Continuity and thus "writer's notes" didn't really get good until the Silver Age and not always then, depending on the writers and editors.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes plenty of [evidence](http://www.adherents.com/lit/comics/Superman.html).

### Here are some snippets:

> Clark Kent was raised as a Methodist. While growing up in Smallville, Kansas, Clark Kent attended Sunday church services at the local Methodist church with his mother, Martha Kent, every week until he was fourteen years old. These aspects of the character are not speculative, but are canonical - established by in-continuity published DC Comics. **Action Comics #850 (August 2007)**, for example, *identifies Methodism by name as the denomination that Clark Kent and his mother attended*.

[image]

Note the overt church in the background.

> ... For example, popular comic book writer Mark Millar (Superman Adventures; Superman: Red Son) has written that Superman is a Methodist. Curt Swan, one of the best-known and most influential Superman artists, was raised Presbyterian but also attended Methodist churches while growing up (see: http://theages.superman.ws/swan.php). **With the publication of *Action Comics #850* in June 2007, the Methodist denominational affiliation of the Kent family was explicitly and overtly established, if it had not already been so.**

And from one of the writers:

> **BRUCE BACHAND [interviewer]**: Do you see Superman as a man who prays and/or worships God regularly? If so, what would the Man of Steel pray about from your perspective?
>
> **Elliot S! Maggin**: I give all my characters religions. I think I always have. It's part of the backstory. It's part of the process of getting to know a character well enough to write about him or her. ..... Luthor is Jewish (though non-observant, thank heaven). .... **Clark - like the Kents - is Methodist**. Superman is something else, but I never did buy all that Kryptonian "Great Rao" nonsense......
>   
> <sub>Published in Fanzing (The Independent Online DC Comics Fan Magazine) Issue #9, August 1998 (http://www.fanzing.com/mag/fanzing09/iview.shtml; viewed 6 December 2005):</sub>

The evidence from the link goes on, but it should be fairly solid now that Superman is Methodist,

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I'm interested in in-universe reflection, so the last paragraph/quote is not relevant. Could you please expand on what specifically is shown/said in AC#850 so I can accept?

Comment: Just to be clear - if that image contains a church that si 100% methodist, that would be fully acceptable. I just don't know enough to be sure, to me it looks like a "generic church" due to lack of knowledge of the topic.

Comment: @DVK I'm making enquiries...